# SQL recursion query

Tags: sql, ms-access, recursion

I am stuck with an issue here.
I have the following table

```
ID     TX_NAME     DT_DATE        ID_SUCCESSOR    
1      Task 1      Jan/01/2012    2
2      Task 2      Jan/02/2012    3
3      Task 3      Jan/01/2012
```

My objective is to create an SQL statement which brings me TX_NAME which its DT_DATE is later and its ID_SUCCESSOR.

For example, ID = 2 is the one I am looking for as it happens after its successor (ID = 3)

Is it possible in a single query?

Thanks

Comment: No, with MS Access this is not possible in a single query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That seems to be a somewhat sweeping statement, what part is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.* from 
TestTable t 
inner join TestTable t2 on t2.id = t.ID_SUCCESSOR
where t.DT_DATE > t2.DT_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but ought to be ok :)

```
SELECT TX_NAME
from MyTable T1
where DT_DATE > (
    SELECT DT_DATE
    from MyTable T2
    where T1.ID_SUCCESSOR = T2.ID
    )
```